# How can I add more to a file when printing stdout to a file, instead of overwriting the file?

Tags: python, file, stdout

Is there any way I can print stdout to a file without it overwriting the file? Then if the file reaches a certain size, then it starts to overwrite the file? Is there a way I can achieve this in python? I already know how to print stdout to a file like this:

```
sys.stdout = open('file.txt', 'w')
# Print some stuff
```

Unfortunately, with my limited knowledge of python, I can't do what I want to achieve, is there any way I can do this, or is it not possible? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you be more specific - it *almost* sounds like you're after the `logging` module... but it's difficult to tell as it's currently stated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `open('file.txt', 'a')` to append to the end of the file rather than overwrite.
Starting to overwrite once you reach a certain size is more complicated: you need to write your new text at the right location in the file, which may be complicated if your file's lines have a variable length.